# Using BibTeX for bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I created a BibTex database for the references for my document. The `abc.bib` which resides in the same directory as `.tex` file resides.

```
     @conference{ref1,
     author  = {Chris H. Q. Ding and Xiaofeng He and Hangyuan Zha},
     title   = {A spectral method to separate disconnected and nearly-disconnected web graph componenets},
     booktitle = {KDD},
     year    = 2001
     }
```

and i have embedded following code in the `.tex` file.

```
    \bibliographystyle{plane}
    \bibliography{abc}
    \end{document}
```

I am using kile to compile and run the command   `Build->quickBuild`  and i get the following error. Moreover i don't get any citation in my report. Instead i see inverted `?`.What can be the reason for it?

[EDIT]

One thing i forget to mentioned here is , i am getting following error message:

```
 [BibTex]thesis.aur => thesis.bbl(bibtex)
 [BibTex] finished with exit code 2
```

and the package inclusion is :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
```

Comment: Did you run latex again after compiling the bibliography? You need to run latex twice to get the references correctly. The general idea is: latex -> bibtex -> latex. Also, I try your example; if you fix the typo "plain" instead of "plane" it works.

Comment: Please provide a full compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo. It should be `\bibliographystyle{plain}` not `plane`.

Comment: ya that was the typo.Thanks for pointing it, I tested it after correcting even i am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Kile, but you should make sure that the Quickbuild you are executing includes running the command bibtex as well. See for help:

http://kile.sourceforge.net/showscreenshot.php?id=12

Make sure you run the latex command, then the bibtex and the a couple more times the latex again.

One last thing that I noticed, but I'm not sure if this is mandatory to change, is the year 2001 in your .bib file should be within curly brackets {}.

Comment: There are several options on what Kile's *QuickBuild* will do. The default one is set to "PDFLaTeX+ViewPDF".

Answer (score 0):

I use Kile, and I also has this error reported all the time. But my references can get into the PDF correctly all the time regardless of this error. What I do is whenever I want to embed a new reference, I will run: PDFLaTeX --> BibTeX --> PDFLaTeX.

Hope it helps.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 0):

If you had more than this entry: Check your citations in file `abc.bib` for any missing deliminators `,` or a `}`. To run bibtex in the console might give you some more hints.